# Change one div's class using another div's click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in a class that is writing an online UNO game (this is not a graded assignment, just a class project). I am currently trying to develop the functionality to play a card. Basically, the player needs to be able to click on a card in their hand and have it appear in the discard pile. I thought about animating this, but we have 1 week left and a lot to get done, so my idea is to just have the player double-click on the card and it will appear in the discard pile.

Each of the cards in all the players' hands are separate divs created in javascript via information from the back end. I do not, however, have the code connected to the back end yet because I need to be able to test my functions and script now. Thus I have currently hard-coded the cards.

The discard pile has one card on it. I have determined that we don't actually need every single card to be placed on the discard pile. Rather, it should be enough to change the color and the rank of the card on the discard pile to reflect the card discarded and just eliminate that div from the player's hand. If you think I am wrong about this, please tell me.

That is where my problem is. I have a bit of script here that is supposed to erase the color of the discard pile card and replace it with the color of the div card that was clicked on in the player's hand. Here is the code (full code posted later in the post):

```js
/*
The double-click on the card in the player's hand does erase the color from the discard pile card, but it doesn't add the color of the card from the hand to the discard pile card. I have tried different variations of the code, but none seem to work. Can anyone help me? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?
*/


$(document).ready(function() {


  function playCardThisPlayer(game) {
    currCardColor = $(this).color;
    $(".card").dblclick(function() {
      $(".discardPile").removeClass(game.discardPile.color);
      $(".discardPile").addClass.$(currCardColor);
    });
  }

  playCardThisPlayer(gameTurn);

  var gameTurn = {
    deckCount: 40,
    discardPile: {
      color: "yellow",
      rank: "2"
    },
    players: [{
        name: "David", //players[0].name
        hand: [{
            color: "yellow",
            rank: "3"
          },
          {
            color: "blue",
            rank: "3"
          },
          {
            color: "red",
            rank: "4"
          },
          {
            color: "black",
            rank: "w"
          },
          {
            color: "blue",
            rank: "7"
          },
          {
            color: "blue",
            rank: "8"
          },
          {
            color: "green",
            rank: "S"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Dan", //players[1].name
        hand: 4 //players[1].hand
      },
      {
        name: "John", //players[2].name
        hand: 5 //players[2].hand
      },
      {
        name: "Kent", //players[3].name
        hand: 10 //players[3].hand
      },
      {
        name: "Amy",
        hand: 15
      }
    ]
  };

  function makePlayerList(game) {
    for (i = 0; i < game.players.length; i++) {
      $(".list").append("<p>" + (i + 1) + ". " + game.players[i].name + "</p>");
    }
  }

  makePlayerList(gameTurn);

  function createCards(game) {
    var currPlayer = game.players[0];
    var hand = $("<div class='hand'></div>");
    for (var i = 0; i < currPlayer.hand.length; i++) {
      var card = $("<div class='card'></div>" /*<div class='playerLabel'></div>"*/ );
      card.addClass(".oval-shape");
      var corner1 = $("<div></div>");
      var middle = $("<div></div>");
      var corner2 = $("<div></div>");
      var oval = $("<div></div>")
      corner1.append(currPlayer.hand[i].rank);
      corner1.addClass("corner1");
      middle.append(currPlayer.hand[i].rank);
      middle.addClass("middle");
      oval.addClass("oval-shape");
      card.append(oval);
      corner2.append(currPlayer.hand[i].rank);
      corner2.addClass("corner2");
      card.append(corner1);
      card.append(middle);
      card.append(corner2);
      card.addClass(currPlayer.hand[i].color);
      hand.append(card);
    }

    $("#table").append(hand);
  }

  function createCardBacks(game) {
    for (var i = 1; i < game.players.length; i++) {
      var hand = $("<div class='hand'></div>");
      for (var j = 0; j < game.players[i].hand; j++) {
        var cardBack = $("<div class='cardBack black'></div>");
        var oval = $("<div></div>")
        oval.addClass("oval-shape");
        cardBack.append(oval);
        hand.append(cardBack);
      }
      $("#table").append(hand);
    }
  }

  function createDiscardPile(game) {
    var topOfDiscardPile = $(".discardPile");
    topOfDiscardPile.addClass(".oval-shape");
    var corner1 = $("<div></div>");
    var middle = $("<div></div>");
    var corner2 = $("<div></div>");
    var oval = $("<div></div>")
    corner1.append(game.discardPile.rank);
    corner1.addClass("corner1");
    middle.append(game.discardPile.rank);
    middle.addClass("middle");
    oval.addClass("oval-shape");
    topOfDiscardPile.append(oval);
    corner2.append(game.discardPile.rank);
    corner2.addClass("corner2");
    topOfDiscardPile.append(corner1);
    topOfDiscardPile.append(middle);
    topOfDiscardPile.append(corner2);
    topOfDiscardPile.addClass(game.discardPile.color);
  }

  createCards(gameTurn);
  createCardBacks(gameTurn);
  createDiscardPile(gameTurn);

  function playCardThisPlayer(game) {
    currCardColor = $(this).color;
    $(".card").dblclick(function() {
      $(".discardPile").removeClass(game.discardPile.color);
      $(".discardPile").addClass.$(currCardColor);
    });
  }

  playCardThisPlayer(gameTurn);

  function fan(container, angle) {
    var num = $(container).children().length;
    var rotate = -angle * Math.floor(num / 2);
    $(container).children().each(function() {
      $(this).data("rotate", rotate);
      $(this).css("transform", "translate(-50%,0) rotate(" + rotate + "deg)");
      $(this).css("transform-origin", "0 100%");
      rotate += angle;
    });

    $(container).children().mouseenter(function() {
      var rotate = parseInt($(this).data("rotate")) * Math.PI / 180;
      $(this).css("top", (-3 * Math.cos(rotate)) + "vmin");
      $(this).css("left", (3 * Math.sin(rotate)) + "vmin");
    });
    $(container).children().mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).css("top", 0);
      $(this).css("left", 0);
    });
  }

  var rotate = 0;
  var num = $("#table").children().length;
  var angleInc = 360 / num;
  $("#table").children().each(function(idx) {
    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)");
    $(this).append("<div class='playerLabel'><span>" + (idx + 1) + "</span></div>")
    $(this).css("transform-origin", "50% -18vmin");
    fan(this, (idx == 0) ? 7 : 2.5);
    rotate += angleInc;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #00a651;
}

#table {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #00FF00;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.discardPile {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card,
.discardPile {
  width: 15vmin;
  height: 22vmin;
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #808080;
  border: .3em solid white;
  transition: all 0.125s;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10vmin;
  width: 0;
  height: 22vmin;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.playerLabel {
  margin-top: -10vh;
  background-color: red;
  width: 3vmin;
  height: 3vmin;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.list {
  color: yellow;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  font-size: 3vmin;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.corner1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3.5vmin;
  left: .5vmin;
  top: .5vmin;
  color: white;
}

.corner2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3.5vmin;
  right: .5vmin;
  bottom: .5vmin;
  color: white;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10vmin;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.oval-shape {
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 22vmin;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 7vmin / 15vmin;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(25deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.slide-out {
  top: -3vmin;
}

.cardBack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15vmin;
  height: 22vmin;
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  -webkit-box-shadow: .3vmin .3vmin .7vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: .3vmin .3vmin .7vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-shadow: .2vmin .2vmin 0 #808080;
  border: .3em solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>UNO Cards</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="list"></div>
  <div class="discardPile"></div>
  <div id="table"></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks like just an issue with your syntax. I could be out of touch with what this is doing, but it looks like the .$ after addClass is wrong `$(".discardPile").addClass.$(currCardColor);`

Comment: I tried deleting it and all my cards disappeared.

Comment: Do you have an error in the console?

Comment: No error in the console. I added an alert to give me the value of currCardColor and it comes back as undefined

Comment: So there's your problem